# I cant boot ubuntu

Tags: boot, laptop

I recently nuked my laptop with DBAN so i can install Ubuntu. I put the disk and it shows Ubuntu and let me choose install or test it out but no matter what is choose it stays at the Ubuntu loading screen but never loads up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with DBAN, but ubuntu has it's own very useful partitioning tool called gparted, if the screen that says "install or try" has a disk checker, try using that.  or, try to use a usb to install using unetbootin (available for windows, mac or linux) I have had terrible luck with using an actual CD.  you may need to create a gparted live usb to repartition as well.

Comment: gparted usb i made a bootable usb before